# Section ignored by Sphinx using numpy-style formatting

Tags: python, numpy, python-sphinx

I'm trying to extract from my module the docstrings and build a nice documentation. So here I am with Sphinx, and I can't figure out what's wrong.

My class docstring, inside the `_meta` file:

```
class MasterBlock(object):
    """
    Main class for block architecture. All blocks should inherit this class.    

    Methods
    -------
    main()
        Override it to define the main function of this block.
    add_input(Link object)
        Add a Link object as input.
    add_output(Link object)
        Add a Link as output.
    start()
        Start the main() method as a Process.
    stop()
        Stops the process.
    """
```

my `.rst` :

```
Meta
==========================

.. automodule:: crappy.blocks._meta
    :members:
    :undoc-members:
    :show-inheritance:
```

My configuration file for Sphinx (the part I changed):

```
autoclass_content = 'both'
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc','sphinx.ext.napoleon']
napoleon_numpy_docstring = True
```

When I try `make html`, it works (no error on this module), but it doesn't display the "Methods" section. If I remove it in the docstring, the only difference it makes with the html is that listed method below are no longer links.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should try using the [`numpydoc` Sphinx extension](https://github.com/numpy/numpydoc/). Once you've installed it then you simply include it in your list of Sphinx extensions:

```
extensions = ['sphinx.ext.autodoc', 'sphinx.ext.napoleon', 'numpydoc']
```

In `conf.py` you then have access to the following options:

> - `numpydoc_show_class_members: bool`
>
>   Whether to show all members of a class in the Methods and Attributes sections automatically. `True` by default.
> - `numpydoc_show_inherited_class_members: bool`
>
>   Whether to show all inherited members of a class in the Methods and Attributes sections automatically. If it's false, inherited
>     members won't shown. `True` by default.
> - `numpydoc_class_members_toctree: bool`
>
>   Whether to create a Sphinx table of contents for the lists of class methods and attributes. If a table of contents is made, Sphinx
>     expects each entry to have a separate page. `True` by default.

Comment: I added the `numpydoc` option and all the scipy html theme, and now it works AND it's pretty. Thank you